# Is it legal to switch the bounds of a summation if upper bound is below lower bound?

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm trying to simplify this summation $\sum _{k=1}^i 2^{h-k}$ where $1\leq i\leq h$.  After 
performing variable substitution, however, the upper bound becomes less than the lower bound:

\begin{align}
j=h-k\\
k=1\Rightarrow j=h-1\\
k=i\Rightarrow j=h-i\\
\sum _{k=1}^i 2^{h-k} &= \sum_{j=h-1}^{h-i} 2^j\\
&=\sum _{j=h-i}^{h-1} 2^j \text{ ................. bounds swapped}\\
&=\sum _{j=0}^{h-1} 2^j-\sum _{j=0}^{h-i-1} 2^j\\
&=\frac{2^h-1}{2-1}-\frac{2^{h-i}-1}{2-1}\\
&=2^h-2^{h-i}
\end{align}

Would it be legal to switch the bounds in this case?

Comment: Totally legal as long as you're summing finitely many terms. You're simply taking advantage of commutativity of addition.

Comment: It shouldn't be thought of as swapping the bounds because you shouldn't have written $\sum_{j=h-1}^{h-i}$ in the first place. The bounds are always written such that the lower bound is less than or equal to the upper bound (otherwise the sum is an empty sum). You should have directly written $\sum_{j=h-i}^{h-1}$ as the lowest value is $h-i$ and the highest is $h-1$.

Comment: "Legal" is not the right word... legislatures don't (usually) legislate mathematical rules. Whether it is a valid change that does not affect the value may depend on your conventions: sometimes the convention is that if the upper limit is strictly smaller than the lower limit, then the index is assumed to *decrease* (rather than increase); but in other conventions, if the upper limit is strictly smaller than the lower limit, then the sum is taken to be empty and thus equal to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, it is rather the first step that looks illegal, i.e., I would allow only the direct transition
$$\tag1\sum_{k=1}^i 2^{h-i}=\sum_{j=h-i}^{h-1}2^j,$$
but that depends on how (if at all) you defined $\sum$ when the top bound is below the bottom bound. For example, I would prefer the equation
$$\tag2 \sum_{k=n}^m x_k=x_m+\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}x_k = x_n+\sum_{k=n+1}^m x_k$$
to always be true (and therefore $\sum_{k=n}^m=-\sum_{k=m+1}^{n-1}$) instead of 
$$\tag3 \sum_{k=n}^mx_k=\sum_{k=m}^nx_k,$$
(you can't have both) but your mileage may vary.

But I think the [most common definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Formal_definition) with respect to wrongly ordered bounds is that
$$ \sum_{k=n}^mx_k=0\quad\text{if }m<n$$
(and again, this means you must use the transition $(1)$ directly).  This comes naturally (and thereby differs from $(2)$) by interpreting the index bound notation as a shorthand for summing over a finite set:
$$ \sum_{k=n}^mx_k:=\sum_{k\in\{k\in \Bbb Z\mid n\le k\le m\}}x_k.$$